# Как вывести данные модели во View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*Здравствуйте. Этот пролог выделенный наклонным шрифтом можно пропустить если считаете нужным. Строго не судите я новичок в ruby on rails, мне ещё многому предстоит научиться. Скажу на опережение, я пытался читать покументацию про ассоциации но пока немного глухо в качестве понимания. Возможно на примерах я смогу быстрее понять суть.*

**Сначала вопрос:** у меня есть есть контроллер 1 единственный и в нём есть мои созданные экшены и между ними создана связь. Проблема в том то что не как не могу понять как правильно вывести значения той или иной модели во вьюшку. Как это сделать?

Я пытаюсь сделать сайт с фильмами и изначально поставил цель что у меня URL будет такого вида:

```
http://sitename.ru/movies/3-season/5-episode
```

> **movies** - это контроллер
>
> **season** - action
>
> **episode** - action

## routes.rb

```
get '/movies/:id/:season-season' => 'movies#season', as: 'movies_season'

get '/movies/:id/:season-season/:episode-episode' => 'movies#episode', as: 'movies_episode'
```

## Movies Controller

помимо index, show и так далее у меня есть там 2 моих экшена

```
 def season

    @seasons = @movie.seasons
    @season = @seasons.where(season: params[:season]).first 

 end

  def episode

    # @seasons = @movie.seasons
    @season = Season.where(season: params[:season]).first
    @episode = @season.episodes.where(episode: params[:episode]).first    
 end
```

## model Movie

```
has_many :seasons
```

## model Season

```
  has_many :episodes
  belongs_to :movie
```

## model episode

```
  belongs_to :season
```

## migration Movie

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :moviesdo |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

## migration season

```
class CreateSeasons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :seasons do |t|
      t.integer :season_id
      t.integer :season
      t.belongs_to :movie, :index => true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

## migration episode

```
class CreateEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :episodes do |t|
      t.integer :season_id
      t.integer :episode_id
      t.integer :episode
      t.belongs_to :season, :index => true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

## В папке View

создал два представления:

```
 1. season.html.erb
 2. episode.html.erb
```

Я извиняюсь но я не знаю как правильно даже вопрос поставить. Я как бы хочу что бы зайдя на страницу http://sitename.ru/movies/new я смог сразу ввести и title и номер сезона и номер эпизода.
И ещё я не понимаю как вывести во представлении Episode.html.erb номер эпизода.

Пробовал так

```
<%= @episode.episode %>
```

## получаю ошибку обращаясь по запросу: http://localhost:3000/movies/1/10-season/15-episode

```
undefined method `episodes' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #23):

    @episode = @season.episodes.where(episode: params[:episode]).first
```

Comment: на строке 23 написано что `undefined method `episodes' for nil:NilClass`, а это значит что у тебя пустой @season. Это действие ни чего не вернуло. @season = Season.where(season: params[:season]).first. Попробуй так написать params[:id]. И лучше использовать метод find_by(id: params[:id]) возвращает 1 запись всегда.

Comment: @Andrew Tymchenko, у меня пока не получается добавить ответ на комментарий.
А можете дать ответ на этот вопрос? > Я как бы хочу что бы зайдя на страницу http://sitename.ru/movies/new я смог сразу ввести и title и номер сезона и номер эпизода. И ещё я не понимаю как вывести во представлении Episode.html.erb номер эпизода.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, с чего начать описание того, что у вас не так. Во-первых, у вас существуют колонки `seasons.id` и `seasons.season_id`, и аналогично `episodes.id` и `episodes.episode_id`. Во-вторых, `where(...).first` это `find_by(...)`, но если вам в этом экшене *обязательно* нужен означенный объект, вам нужен `find_by!`, а то и `find`. В-третьих, `season` и `episode` это никакие не действия и заслуживают собственных контроллеров, даже если в них будет только `show`, так вам будет куда проще ориентироваться. В-четвёртых, проблема в данных, которых в вопросе нет. В-пятых, возьмите отладчик.

Comment: Если не знаете с чего начать - вам сюда: http://railsforzombies.org>- все подробно рассказывают)